# Is it possible to have multiple active input methods in Android?

Tags: android, ime

The situation is: I have a bluetooth device that reads microchips codes. I created an IME application that receives that code and writes it to the currently active TextView.

But in order to work, I have to select the IME I've developed as the default keyboard. However, if I do so, the user will no longer be able to use his default keyboard for regular inputs. (The inputs from the bluetooth device will only be used in 1 or 2 fields of many in a form located in a web page.)

Is it possible for an (non-rooted) Android device to be able to listen to two different input methods (other than actually create a keyboard UI in my own IME)?

Comment: Having exactly the same issue here with a bluetooth attach barcode scanner, with the scanner active the Galaxy Tab Active seems to disable the keyboard.